# Is it possible to use the Storage Area Explorer extension for Chrome to copy my OneTab data?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to move away from the problematic OneTab extension. I want to copy all my URLs **with timestamps of each group** to a new extension such as Better OneTab or Tabalanche. The link-copying option in OneTab disregards all timestamps.

The problem is that past answers mention two files in the `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage` directory, which I cannot find at all.

- chrome-extension_chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall_0.localstorage-journal
- chrome-extension_chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall_0.localstorage

So I am trying to think of a workaround, involving the [Storage Area Explorer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storage-area-explorer/ocfjjjjhkpapocigimmppepjgfdecjkb) extension. I go to OneTab’s Manage Extension page in Chrome, open the background page and select the Storage Explorer tab at the top. I expand the `state` section in the `window.localStorage` tab on top, and copy all the Local Storage data (which is in JSON format).

But the JSON data format of every extension is different. How do I go about doing this then?

Comment: "data format of every extension is different" - in that case to make your question answerable you need to show the source format and the target format.

Comment: Sorry for the formatting. The OneTab format is like this:

{"tabGroups":[{"id":"****","tabsMeta":[{"id":"SKEZI6khfPRffx3VXKB-a4","url":"****","title":"****"}],"createDate":1571405012368,"locked":false,"starred":true,"starredDate":1571405017451}

and for better-onetab:
{
  "_id": "5f047b7c343b805693f5f468",
  "color": "",
  "expand": false,
  "pinned": false,
  "tabs": [
   {
    "favIconUrl": "****",
    "pinned": false,
    "title": "****",
    "url": "****"
   },